# Spring Web Flow validator not found

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflow

I am trying to do form validation in Spring Web Flow. For this I am using a validator class, which is named after the model. Just like it is stated in the documentation.
The validator gets instantiated as a bean but is never called during validation. Any pointers on that issue?

**flow config**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.4.xsd">

    <view-state id="createTotpKeyView" view="/templates/totp/create/create" model="key">
        <on-entry>
            <evaluate expression="createTotpKeyAction"/>
        </on-entry>
        <transition on="submit" to="successfullyCreated" bind="true" validate="true"/>
    </view-state>

    <end-state id="successfullyCreated" view="/templates/totp/create/success"/>
</flow>
```

This is the action that is called in the view-state.

**createTotpKeyAction**

```java
@Component
public class CreateTotpKeyAction implements Action
{
    String uid = "random";

    @Override
    public Event execute(RequestContext context) throws Exception
    {
        try
        {
            // Create a TOTP key and put it in the view scope
            TOTPKey totpKey = client.createTotpKeyForUid(uid, null);
            context.getViewScope().put("key", totpKey);

            return new Event(this, "success");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            log.error("Error while creating TOTP key for user: " + uid + ".\n" + e.getMessage());
            // Put response message in flash scope to show it once
            context.getFlashScope().put("fetchingError", true);
            return new Event(this, "error");
        }
    }
}
```

This is the validator I am trying to use. **EDIT** renamed to match documentation.

**KeyValidator**

```java
@Component
public class KeyValidator
    {
        [...]

    public void validateCreateTotpKeyView(TOTPKey key, ValidationContext context)
    {
        System.out.println("VALIDATE VIEW STATE");
    }

    public void validate(TOTPKey key, ValidationContext context)
    {
        System.out.println("DEFAULT VALIDATE");
    }
}
```

I also tried different naming schemes such as `TOTPKeyValidator` or `TotpKeyValidator`. None of them worked.

The only thing that is working, is creating a validation method in the `TOTPKey` class, but I don't want to use that approach.

In addition this is the log file produced during the attempted validation

**Log**

```
Mapping request with URI '/totp/create' to flow with id 'totp/create'
Resuming flow execution with key 'e5s1
Locking conversation 5
Getting flow execution with key 'e5s1'
Getting FlowDefinition with id 'totp/create'
Resuming in org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.MvcExternalContext@2b551393
Restoring [FlowVariable@3b66a2de name = 'key', valueFactory = [BeanFactoryVariableValueFactory@2fbc89 type = TOTPKey]]
Processing user event 'submit'
Resolved model twofa.core.domain.TOTPKey@505439d0
Binding to model
Adding default mapping for parameter 'execution'
Adding default mapping for parameter 'totpKeyId'
Adding default mapping for parameter 'token'
Adding empty value mapping for parameter 'eventId_submit'
Validating model
Event 'submit' returned from view [ServletMvcView@19f8532f view = org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityLayoutView: name '/templates/totp/create/create'; URL [/templates/totp/create/create.vm]]
Executing [Transition@2feb5361 on = submit, to = successfullyCreated]
Exiting state 'createTotpKeyView'
Entering state 'successfullyCreated' of flow 'totp/create'
Executing org.springframework.webflow.action.ViewFactoryActionAdapter@423fa131
Rendering MVC [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityLayoutView: name '/templates/totp/create/success'; URL [/templates/totp/create/success.vm]] with model map [{currentUser=null, flashScope=map[[empty]], flowRequestContext=[RequestControlContextImpl@70144045 externalContext = org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.MvcExternalContext@2b551393, currentEvent = submit, requestScope = map[[empty]], attributes = map[[empty]], messageContext = [DefaultMessageContext@149807b4 sourceMessages = map[[null] -> list[[empty]]]], flowExecution = [FlowExecutionImpl@1c4b2c3e flow = 'totp/create', flowSessions = list[[FlowSessionImpl@6eea5d26 flow = 'totp/create', state = 'successfullyCreated', scope = map['key' -> twofa.core.domain.TOTPKey@73f32d0a]]]]], flowExecutionKey=e5s1, flowExecutionUrl=/totp/create?execution=e5s1, key=twofa.core.domain.TOTPKey@73f32d0a}]
Finished executing org.springframework.webflow.action.ViewFactoryActionAdapter@423fa131; result = success
Completed transition execution.  As a result, the flow execution has ended
Removing flow execution '[Ended execution of 'totp/create']' from repository
Ending conversation 5
Unlocking conversation 5
```

It says `Validating Model` but nothing happens...

Comment: I suggest a read of the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/webflow/2.4.2.RELEASE/reference/html/views.html#view-validation-programmatic-validator). The name of the validator should match the following pattern `${model}Validator`. Your model is named `key`. Your validator should be named `KeyValidator`.

Comment: I tried that, it does not work.

Comment: Make sure that it actually is detected (it has to be in a package covered by Spring Boot else it isn't constructed and will never work).

Comment: It is detected as a bean and gets constructed. I also verified that in the debugger. The constructor is called during startup.

Comment: Then you are configuring additional things and the bean simply isn't visible. However you haven't posted that information.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the configuration. I took a deeper look at the import statements and found the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It came down to a wrong import statement in my validator class.

Using `org.relaxng.datatype.ValidationContext` instead of `org.springframework.binding.validation.ValidationContext` will not work.

Comment: I've done that kind of thing before, not noticing the wrong class chosen in IDE autocomplete :-)