# Spring Web Flow validation not working in IDE

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflow

As a follow up to my last [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43206989/spring-web-flow-validator-not-found) about Web Flow not finding my validator class, I ran into another problem concerning the validation.

When I run my project via `mvn spring-boot:run` the validation works without problems. However, when I run it in Eclipse, STS or IntelliJ via executing the main class as Spring Boot application, validation is not working anymore.

I don't know where to look for hints on this problem. For starters these are my `pom` files. I based them on the [JHipster pom.xml](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/master/pom.xml) because I liked their dev and prod profile implementations.

**Parent pom**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>twofa</groupId>
    <artifactId>2fa-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>../2fa-portal</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <maven-enforcer-plugin.version>1.4.1</maven-enforcer-plugin.version>
        <maven-war-plugin.version>2.6</maven-war-plugin.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <sortpom-maven-plugin.version>2.5.0</sortpom-maven-plugin.version>
        <spring.boot.version>1.4.1.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.release</id>
            <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - SpringSource Bundle Releases</name>
            <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.external</id>
            <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - External Bundle Releases</name>
            <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <defaultGoal>spring-boot:run</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.ekryd.sortpom</groupId>
                <artifactId>sortpom-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${sortpom-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>sort</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <sortProperties>true</sortProperties>
                    <nrOfIndentSpace>4</nrOfIndentSpace>
                    <sortDependencies>groupId,artifactId</sortDependencies>
                    <sortPlugins>groupId,artifactId</sortPlugins>
                    <keepBlankLines>true</keepBlankLines>
                    <expandEmptyElements>false</expandEmptyElements>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-enforcer-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>enforce-versions</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enforce</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <rules>
                        <requireMavenVersion>
                            <message>You are running an older version of Maven. Application requires at least Maven 3.0</message>
                            <version>[3.0.0,)</version>
                        </requireMavenVersion>
                        <requireJavaVersion>
                            <message>You are running an older version of Java. Application requires at least JDK ${java.version}</message>
                            <version>[${java.version}.0,)</version>
                        </requireJavaVersion>
                    </rules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Force alphabetical order to have a reproducible build -->
                    <runOrder>alphabetical</runOrder>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                        <include>**/Test*.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/Abstract*.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Portal pom**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>2fa-parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>twofa</groupId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <relativePath>../2fa-parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>2fa-portal</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>2fa-portal</name>

    <prerequisites>
        <maven>3.0.0</maven>
    </prerequisites>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-velocity</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <!-- creates 2fa-portal.war file -->
        <!-- Resource filtering to fill in placeholders "@...@" in properties -->
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/application*.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/application*.properties</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <finalName>2fa-portal</finalName>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.7</version>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-filtering</artifactId>
                            <version>1.3</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                    <configuration>
                        <delimiters>
                            <delimiter>@</delimiter>
                            <!-- delimiter that doesn't clash with Spring ${} placeholders -->
                        </delimiters>
                        <useDefaultDelimiters>false</useDefaultDelimiters>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${maven-war-plugin.version}</version>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
            <properties>
                <!-- log configuration -->
                <logback.loglevel>DEBUG</logback.loglevel>
                <!-- default Spring profile -->
                <spring.profiles.active>dev</spring.profiles.active>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
                    <optional>true</optional>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>test</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.5</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <filesets>
                                <fileset>
                                    <directory>target/</directory>
                                </fileset>
                            </filesets>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>

                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build-info</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>false</executable>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
            <properties>
                <spring.profiles.active>test</spring.profiles.active>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.5</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <filesets>
                                <fileset>
                                    <directory>target/</directory>
                                </fileset>
                            </filesets>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>

                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build-info</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>false</executable>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
            <properties>
                <spring.profiles.active>prod</spring.profiles.active>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a problem with Spring Devtools together with Spring Web Flow. Further information and the workaround can be found [at this Spring Boot issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7912).

Quoting the workaround:

> I think the problem is due to the separation of restart and base class loaders and is easily solved by adding the following `spring-devtools.properties` entry
>
> ```
> restart.include.spring=/spring-.*\.jar
> ```